# ¿Por qué crea una lista auxiliar?

Tags: python, lista, filtro, tuplas

En Python, estoy tratando de filtrar un csv por paises, y en la solución, no entiendo el motivo de por qué crea una lista auxiliar, en vez de añadir la tupla directamente a la lista. Poblaciones es una lista que me dan a través de una función de lectura, y pais es un string por el que filtro.

Este es el código de la solución:

```
def filtra_por_pais(poblaciones, pais):
   lista=[]
    for nombre, codigo, año, censo in poblaciones:
        if nombre==pais:
            lista_aux=[]
            tupla=(año, censo)
            lista_aux.append(tupla)
            lista.append(lista_aux)
    return lista
```

Comment: Se usa una lista auxiliar para no modificar la lista original.

Comment: Habría que ver el contexto de la pregunta, pero a priori esa lista auxiliar es completamente innecesaria. Parece que su única función es hacer que la lista de resultados contenga en su interior listas (de un solo elemento, los cuales son tuplas). Es decir que la `lista` sea `[ [(año, censo)], [(año, censo)], ...]`. Esto ya es bastante raro por lo que a mi juicio es un error de interpretación de lo que se pide. Pero aún si es eso lo que se pide, se puede hacer `lista.append([(año,censo)])` siendo innecesarias las variables `lista_aux` y `tupla`.

Comment: Es más, la función podría ser una sola línea, usando comprensiones de listas: `return [ [(año,censo)] for nombre, c, año, censo in poblaciones if nombre==pais]`